# How to adjust an image size with a progressive scaling on viewport resize

Tags: html, css

I have a div called site-title that keeps the title of my site. I want to add an image to the left of the title using CSS. I could do it as follows:

```
.site-title::before {
   content: "";
   background: url("logo.jpg");
   background-size: 200px 200px;
   position: absolute;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
}
```

This works fine, after I add also some padding to the title, etc. But the image is 200px x 200px and doesn't scale with the page. I would like it to become smaller when it wouldn't fit anymore. How can I do this?

BTW, this is a hack on a Wordpress site. I want to use a CSS trick like above to avoid having to deal with the PHP, etc.

Edit: just removed float: left;

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Forget the float: left.

Comment: width: auto; max-width: 200px;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could limit the width and height of your pseudoelement to the width of the viewport (using `vw` units), and defining also a max-width like so

```
.site-title::before {
   content: "";
   background: url("logo.jpg");
   background-size: cover;
   position: absolute;
   max-width: 200px;
   max-height: 200px;
   width: 20vw;
   height: 20vw;
}
```

The pseudoelement will begin to reduce its size when the viewport is less than `1000px`. Under a given breakpoint you could also hide the pseudoelement.

---

Also, doing some basic math you could calculate your width and height values so the element progressively appears over (or disappears under) a given viewport size, e.g.

```css
div {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  background: #9bc;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: calc(0.38461 * 100vw - 184px);
  width: calc(0.38461 * 100vw - 184px);
}
```

```html
<div>
   I will disappear when the viewport is wide less than 480px
</div>
```

---

**How it works**

Let say you want to define a viewport range (e.g. `[480px .. 1000px]`) so that the element can resize from `0` to its maximum value (*upper* limited by a fixed `max-width` and a `max-height`): then you could use the [equation of the line from two points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation) injected into the css `calc()` function

Here's the simple calculations behind those values that I've made (so you can see how to change the range of the element visibility as you prefer)

[image]

---

**Update as of Dec. 2020**

With the introduction of some useful CSS functions like [min()/max()/clamp()](https://web.dev/min-max-clamp/) the style could be simplified on modern browser in this way

```
 .site-title::before {
     height: min(200px, calc(0.38461 * 100vw - 184px));
     width: min(200px, calc(0.38461 * 100vw - 184px));
 }
```

Comment: This is a great answer. How can I hide the element however?

Comment: @Fernando,  use a media query to show the pseudoelement only after a min-width, or just apply some math :)

Answer (score -4):

Use
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
In css...