# Is there a way to make CSS calc() never be a negative value?

Tags: css, css-calc

I have the following code which works great with centering my content until the `vh` is less then `650px`.  I was wondering if there was a way to make this value never go below `0` only using CSS `calc`.

```
.my-margin-top {
    margin-top: calc(50vh - 325px);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calc of max, or max of calc in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617248/calc-of-max-or-max-of-calc-in-css)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Premising that there's no way to bound the values computed by `calc()` you could use a mediaquery when `max-height` is at most `650px`

```
.my-margin-top {
    margin-top: calc(50vh - 325px);
}

@media all and (max-height: 650px) {
   .my-margin-top {
       margin-top: 0;
   }
}
```

or you might also revert the logic by wrapping the existing rule into a `min-height` mediaquery

```
@media all and (min-height: 650px) {
   .my-margin-top {
       margin-top: calc(50vh - 325px);
   }
}
```

Comment: great answer i was making a comment to change that to `max-height`, which you did before i got it out.  I can't believe I wasn't thinking of a media query.

Comment: @cmorrissey: To be fair, your use case just *happens* to feature viewport units which lends itself to media queries. Generally speaking, you simply can't clamp the result of a calc() expression to a certain range of values - CSS would need to provide some form of min() and max() for that.

Comment: @BoltClock an exception would occur when calc() is computing an height/width so you could limit with min/max-height/width (also without mediaqueries), see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35505372/1098851

Comment: Yes, these are entirely property-dependent and don't apply in the general case. I've posted an answer now with more details. I also upvoted your answer.

Comment: Be aware this is possible now! max(), min(), and clamp() are available in CSS now. So for the poster's question, one answer would be: max(0, 50vh-325px). See this stackoverflow question for further information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617248/calc-of-max-or-max-of-calc-in-css

Answer (score 4):

To answer the general question:

> Is there a way to make CSS calc() never be a negative value?

The answer is no, because CSS does not provide a way to manually constrain (or clamp) a quantity to some minimum or maximum value.

Whether or not a number or a length may be *natively* restricted to a certain range is dependent on the property that has this `calc()` value. From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#calc-range):

> The value resulting from an expression must be clamped to the range allowed in the target context.
>
> > These two are equivalent to 'width: 0px' since widths smaller than 0px are not allowed.
> >
> > ```
> > width: calc(5px - 10px);
> > width: 0px;
> > ```

For example, while negative values for `margin` and `z-index` are valid, negative values for `border-width`, `padding`, `height`, `width` and so on are not. The specifics of these are almost always defined in the specification for the respective property.

As you happen to be using viewport units in your example, you can employ media queries in conjunction with them as [demonstrated by fcalderan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35605852/is-there-a-way-to-make-css-calc-never-be-a-negative-value/35605906#35605906).

Answer (score 2):

In the latest browser versions there is [`max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max) function in CSS:

```
.my-margin-top {
    margin-top: max(50vh - 325px, 0);
}
```

[Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max#Browser_compatibility): Firefox 75+, Chrome/Edge: 79+, Safari: 11.1+

There is also [`clamp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp): `clamp(0, 50vh - 325px, 100vh)`, where `100vh` is an upper bound. But this is [not in Safari yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp#Browser_compatibility), although can be simulated with `min()` and `max()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this trick:
`calc((#{$gap} + 1.5rem) / -1);` will result `calc(-32px + -1.5rem)`

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like:

```
.my-margin-top {
    margin-top: calc((50vh - 325px) * (-1));
}
```

Multiplying your calc by `-1` makes it a negative value.